# Removing a legend in octave

Tags: octave

I use fplot to plot function like this:

```
fitnessFunction = @(x) x.^2;
fplot(fitnessFunction, [0 32]);
```

Octave then automatically inserts a legend box in the top right corner with the text "@(x) x.^2". What can I do if I don't want that box? I also still want to be able to add axis descriptions and a title. It seems simple, but the internet didn't have a good answer (or I'm too stupid to look).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete it:

```
fitnessFunction = @(x) x.^2;
fplot(fitnessFunction, [0 32]);
delete (findobj ("tag", "legend"))
```

[image: fplot without legend]

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
legend("off")
```

This turns off the legend. In the lines afterwards you can add more details for the plot, like axis description,...